# Storing Config Values

Tags: c#, mysql-connector

Wondering if I am going about this the right way.  I am creating a C# application that loads a few variables from my App.Config.xml file.  I am loading these into a "config" class (Config.cs) along with other variables that I am loading from a MySQL database.  This is what my class looks like so far:

```
 class Config
    {
        public static string ServerHostname = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerHostname"];
        public static string SoftwareVersion = "v0.1a";
        public static int StationID = DBConnector.GetStationID();
        public static string StationDescription = DBConnector.GetStationDescription();
        public static string StationName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StationName"];
    }
```

I am using Config.StationName to pull the Config.StationID and Config.StationDescription from a MySQL database like this in DBConnector.cs:

```
public static int GetStationID()
    {
        try
        {
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
            conn.Open();
            string sql = "select station_id from station_master where station_name = @station_name limit 1";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@station_name", Config.StationName);
            object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            conn.Close();
            return Convert.ToInt32(result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorConnection += ex.ToString();
            return 0;
        }
    }
    public static string GetStationDescription()
    {
        try
        {
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
            conn.Open();
            string sql = "select station_description from station_master where station_id = '" + Config.StationID +"' limit 1";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
            // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@station_name", Config.StationName.ToString());
            object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            conn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show(sql);
            return (result.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorGenericDBException += ex.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(ErrorGenericDBException);
            return "Error";
        }
    }
```

The DBConnector.GetStationID class works fine.  It returns the int value of my station.  But when I try to display the Config.StationDescription, it throws an exception of System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object at Namespace.DBConnector.GetStationDescription().

I thought that since I was using a static class for Config.StationName, i don't have to create an instance to refer to it.  I need help to understand why its throwing an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it looks like you might be mixing up what part of the code has the problem. Since you're saying that it's `GetSTationDescription` that throws, I'm not sure why you then assume `StationName` has a problem?

I'd take a look at the line `object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();`, if you put a breakpoint on the line after that, does result have a value?

Another issue is that you're currently only closing the connection if an exception is not thrown, it would be safer to have the `conn.Close();` inside a `finally` statement (or use a `using` statement so you don't have to worry about closing it).

Comment: I actually found out what the problem was... in my Config class, I needed to declare the settings that came from the App.Config FIRST... I just moved public static string StationName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StationName"]; up to the top of the list and it works great now.  But I have started to use a finally statement for my connections.  Thanks for the tip!